# How to get devicess connected to a wifi router?

Tags: openwrt

How to know the signal strength of the client or devices which are connected to the router. is there any c code or any command to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

It is shown in web interface in the **Overview** tab, **Associated Stations** section.

Command: `iwinfo wlan0 assoclist`

See more: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/faq/faq.wireless#how_to_get_a_list_of_connected_clients